# Did I solve this correctly?

Tags: geometry, circles, area

The dots are centers of circles and I’m solving for shaded areas.

[image: Problem + Work]

$a=16\sqrt3$

$\pi4^2=\dfrac{\pi16}2$

$a+b=\pi8^2\cdot\dfrac16$
$a+b=\pi64\cdot\dfrac16$
$16\sqrt3+b=\pi64\cdot\dfrac16$
$b=\pi64\cdot\dfrac16-16\sqrt3$

$c=8\pi-\dfrac{32}3\pi+16\sqrt3$

$\boldsymbol{48\sqrt3-8\pi}$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures in this way.

Comment: Well done for sharing your thoughts though . . .

Comment: The part you went wrong is assuming $a+b$ is one-sixth of a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equilateral triangle $a$ has area $16\sqrt3$ as you calculated, and the three semicircles have total area $24\pi$. The complete circle has radius $\frac23×4\sqrt3=\frac8{\sqrt3}$ – its centre coincides with the triangle's centroid, which is $\frac23$ of the way from vertex to opposite median – so the circle's area is $\frac{64\pi}3$. The shaded area is therefore $16\sqrt3+24\pi-\frac{64\pi}3=16\sqrt3+\frac{8\pi}3$.